# Maven compilation error for Cipher class in jce.jar

Tags: java, maven, encryption, jce

I tried with executing sample class which uses `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` it is working, but when I tried with maven clean install command, maven is throwing compilation exceptions.

> **ERROR : package javax.crypto does not exist**
>
> **error: cannot find symbol
>
> Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
>
> ^**

I see that jce.jar file in JRE system library. Do we need to add any dependency to use the Cipher class  in maven?

***I'm using jdk 1.7***

Here is the stack trace for maven `-e clean install`:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project SaaSCommon: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
```

Comment: is your maven build using the same java as you are using within your ide?

Comment: It could be that your are compiling against an *execution environment* that does not include any `javax` packages, as `javax` is (more or less) an extension of the standard API.

Comment: Yes, I'm using same environment in my IDE and maven build.

Comment: To add the javax.crypto libary explicitly, Will you please give me the maven artifacts dependency for jce.jar ? or Do we need to add any bundle/unpacking plugins to pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the below compile arguments.

```
<compilerArguments><bootclasspath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar:${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</bootclasspath></compilerArguments>
```